# bulk write in py2neo from a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have the following data, which represents the distances between two objects.

```
data = [[('123','234'), 10],
        [('134','432'), 12],

       ]
```

I would like to insert this into neo4j via py2neo v3:

```
for e, p in enumerate(data):
    #
    id_left  = p[0][0]
    id_right = p[0][1]    
    distance = p[1]
    #
    left  = Node("_id", id_left)
    right = Node("_id", id_right)
    G.merge(left)
    G.merge(right)
    r = Relationship(left,'TO', right, distance=distance)
    G.create(r)
    #
```

But I find this to be very, very slow. What's the best of speeding this up? I've looked around but haven't found any code example that illustrates clearly how to go about it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently you are using wrongly py2neo to create nodes, you current code produce the following :

[image]

As you can see, the first parameter you give to the `Node` object are the label and the second parameter should be a map of properties.

This is slow because `MERGE` has nothing to match on.

This is a corrected version of your code that will use a label `MyNode` and a property `id` :

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
graph = Graph(password="password")

data = [

    [('123','234'), 10],
    [('134','432'), 12],
]


for e, p in enumerate(data):
    #
    id_left  = p[0][0]
    id_right = p[0][1]    
    distance = p[1]
    #
    left  = Node("MyNode", id=id_left)
    right = Node("MyNode", id=id_right)
    graph.merge(left)
    graph.merge(right)
    r = Relationship(left,'TO', right, distance=distance)
    graph.create(r)
```

Which will produce the following graph :

[image]

For most performance when you start to have thousands of `MyNode` nodes, you can add a unique constraint on the `id` property :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:MyNode) ASSERT m.id IS UNIQUE;
```

Now this code is making 3 calls to Neo4j, the most performant is to use cypher directly :

```
data = [

    [('123','234'), 10],
    [('134','432'), 12],
]


params = []
for x in data:
    params.append({"left": x[0][0], "right": x[0][1], "distance": x[1] })


q = """
UNWIND {datas} AS data
MERGE (m:MyNode {id: data.left })
MERGE (m2:MyNode {id: data.right })
MERGE (m)-[r:TO]->(m2)
SET r.distance = data.distance
"""

graph.run(q, { "datas": params })
```

Which will result in the same graph as above.

Comment: thanks, with the cypher query I get a factor of 4 speed up, even after correcting the code